# misleading concept of future and async programming in flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, future

I found it a bit confused with the concept of `Future` and `async` programming.

By definition, `Future` is a type that async function will return in `Future`.

The purpose is that we want the program to keep running while it is still waiting for the result of the `async` function.

What I dont understand is that, every often/always, I saw people using `async` with `await` which stop proceeding the program until it gets the result from async function called.

Arent we come to full circle? At first, `async` comes in for the situation that we dont want to wait for program taking time. But now, we use `async` with `await` in which we wait until the result is there

Comment: by using `await someFuture` it does not mean your whole app "waits" here and you cannot interact with your app - `await` is basically some syntactic sugar for something like: `someFuture.then()`

Comment: when your say "it does not mean your whole app "waits" here and you cannot interact with your app " , I did really tested that the program really waited there before procedding  until the "someFuture" return. 
For example, Without await: main ->  async function(takes some time) ->  main(continue even though async havent finished)
With await: main ->  async function(takes some time until it finished) ->  main(only after async)

Comment: ok, make a `Row` with two `ElevatedButton`s - in first button's `onClick` do `await Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 1));` and in the second button's `onClick` just `print('foo bar')` - now press the first button so that `await Future.delayed` is called and then press the second button several times, what you see on the logs?

Comment: Oh, with await,  Sub-sequential program would also be blocked like traditional programming. The only difference is that some event, with await,  could still be triggered while , in traditional one, whole program would be freezed until the future return , right?

Comment: run `void main() {
print('one');
foo();
print('two');
}

foo() async {
print('foo one');
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
print('foo two');
}` at https://dartpad.dartlang.org/, what do you see? does `foo` method blocks everything for 3 seconds?

Comment: one
foo one
two ---> 3 s later --->
foo two
But I am not sure if it blocked everything within that 3 s ....

Comment: but you can see that it is not `one` `foo one` `foo two` and finally `two` - it means that `print('two');` is called before `foo` method really returns - so really `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3))` does not block your whole app

Answer (score 0):

It is not always necessary to use `await` with a future. `await` can be used if you want to do further processing with the data.
Example:

```
Future<int> _getInt()async{
Future.delay(Duration(seconds:3)); //simulating network delay
return 7;
}

void _add() async{
int res = await _getInt() + 10; //need to await because we are going to use a future variable
_putInt(res); //not nesscary to await if you don't want to handle the response 
/* Ex: var result = await _putInt(); // if you want to handel the response
 if (result.statusCode==200){
        // handle success
}else{
 // handle error
}*/

}

Future _putInt(int number)async{
var res  = await http.post('url',body:{'data':number});
return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your institution is right, we use `Future` and `async` as it is nonblocking and follows an event loop approach, meaning there is a callback to the `Future` when it is ready to execute.

Coming to your point, I have done this myself a lot of time. And neither approach is wrong.
But when it comes to Flutter, it is in your best interest that you don't do anything else when running an async function because dart is single-threaded.
This can be blocking sometimes depending on the work of the function.
This can also be simply for UX as some data would be critical to your application and you shouldn't allow the user to do anything else until it is loaded.

Comment: So, what you mean is that it is ,for the benefits of app, simply that we need to write await. Therefore, we dont really need the async feature at all. However, if most of the time we dont really need a non-blocking feature, why dont we just simply use a traditional way to write code? Adding a async key words and then put a await to reverse its non blocking feature seems strange to me

Comment: No No, you've got me wrong, I'm not saying we don't need async. We do need async, if not for async, the app would freeze until that function was executed as it takes time. We need async and await for sure to complete something like an API call. but I'm just saying we don't need to show a LoadingIndicator for example, but its best if we do.